# Node-webshot - Image not being generated on server but same code generates image locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js

I am using webshot on my node (sails js) project to convert an HTML string to an image and then upload that image to a S3 bucket. When I run it on my local machine, it works fine i.e it generates an image and I am able to upload that image to s3 bucket. But when I run the same code on a EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16), it doesn't work. It doesn't create any image and hence nothing gets uploaded.

Here is my code -

```
var htmlString = '<div>a long html string</div>';
webshot(htmlString,'img.png', options, function(err) {
fs.readFile('img.png', function (err, data){
   if(err){
     console.log('error reading file');
   }else{
     var params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: 'customPNGs/'+'img.png',
            Body: data,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            ContentType: 'image/png'
     };
     s3.putObject(params, function (err, res) {
       if (err) {
          sails.log.error("Error uploading data: ", err);
     } else {
          console.log('uploaded')                  
     }
  });
}
});
```

I tried doing the uploading directly to S3 using streams but it uploads a 0kb file. Here is my code using the stream -

```
var renderStream = webshot(quitImageHTML, null, options);
var ss = '';
renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
  ss+=data.toString('binary');
});
renderStream.on('end', function() {
    //upload using the above code
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems that `webshot` uses `phantomjs` internally and `phantomjs` has a secret dependency called `libfontconfig` which is not present in its documentation and dependency section.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904

Once I installed the dependency, it started working.